# android - How to integrate magnifying glass to my app

Tags: android

I want to integrate "magnifying glass" in my android app.The Magnifying glass should appear when long pressed on a certain point on image then particular part of image should appear in magnifying glass with zooming  that touched area.I searched many websites about this magnifier but i don't found any useful link/data about magnifying glass. Is it possible to implement in android?

Comment: good question is this